# Android Studio dependency incompatible

Tags: java, android

I just want to know how to fix this issue with incompatibility with dependencies on android studio. I am trying to follow the steps on setting up firebase but could not find any solution with this incompatibility. Please help

[image]

Comment: Its just telling you right away what the ussue is. You are using diffrent versions of dependency that you added in the gradel files

Comment: yes, i suppose it was just a warning since it did proceed on the build. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

That is because Firebase libraries is using support libraries implicitly. You need to override the incompatible libraries by adding the clashed support libraries but with the same current version. For your case, you need to override `support-media-compat`. You can add the following dependencies to your dependencies block:

```
dependencies {

  implementation "com.android-support:support-media-compat:28.0.0"
  implementation "com.android-support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0"
  implementation "com.android-support:support-v4:28.0.0"

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will give it a try. Have a nice day